# Default ordering in C# vs. F#

Tags: c#, string, sorting, f#, collation

Consider the two fragments of code that simply order strings in `C#` and `F#` respectively:

C#:

```cs
var strings = new[] { "Tea and Coffee", "Telephone", "TV" };
var orderedStrings = strings.OrderBy(s => s).ToArray();
```

F#:

```ml
let strings = [| "Tea and Coffee"; "Telephone"; "TV" |]
let orderedStrings =
    strings
    |> Seq.sortBy (fun s -> s)
    |> Seq.toArray
```

These two fragments of code return different results:

- C#: Tea and Coffee, Telephone, TV
- F#: TV, Tea and Coffee, Telephone

In my specific case I need to correlate the ordering logic between these two languages (one is production code, and one is part of a test assertion). This poses a few questions:

- Is there an underlying reason for the differences in ordering logic?
- What is the recommended way to overcome this "problem" in my situation?
- Is this phenomenon specific to strings, or does it apply to other .NET types too?

**EDIT**

In response to several probing comments, running the fragments below reveals more about the exact nature of the differences of this ordering:

F#:

```
let strings = [| "UV"; "Uv"; "uV"; "uv"; "Tv"; "TV"; "tv"; "tV" |]
let orderedStrings =
    strings
    |> Seq.sortBy (fun s -> s)
    |> Seq.toArray
```

C#:

```
var strings = new[] { "UV", "Uv", "uv", "uV", "TV", "tV", "Tv", "tv" };
var orderedStrings = strings.OrderBy(s => s).ToArray();
```

Gives:

- C#: tv, tV, Tv, TV, uv, uV, Uv, UV
- F#: TV, Tv, UV, Uv, tV, tv, uV, uv

The lexicographic ordering of strings differs because of a difference in the underlying order of characters:

- C#: "aAbBcCdD...tTuUvV..."
- F#: "ABC..TUV..Zabc..tuv.."

Comment: Seems to work 'fine' if you do `(fun s -> s.ToLower())`

Comment: That's very odd... I'd really expect this to work fine in F#. If you have words which start with different letters, how do they show up in F#?

Comment: Thanks @leppie - that's a good solution to the "string case".  My actual code is more generic - relying on comparison implementations.  Handling strings as a special case would be acceptable if I knew this was an anomaly - but I suspect there is more going on than I understand....

Comment: Fine with [| "Tea and Coffee"; "Telephone"; "Tv" |] |> Array.sort has to be the capitalisation

Comment: According to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073227/why-is-fs-seq-sortby-much-slower-than-linqs-ienumerablet-orderby-extension) F#'s `sortBy` method does not use Linq's `OrderBy()`.

Comment: Whoops - I misread. For some reason I thought that the F# version had "Telephone" before "Tea and Coffee", which would be odd.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See section 8.15.6 of the [language spec](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/3.0/FSharpSpec-3.0-final.pdf).

Strings, arrays, and native integers have special comparison semantics, everything else just goes to `IComparable` if that's implemented (modulo various optimizations that yield the same result).

In particular, F# strings use *ordinal* comparison by default, in contrast to most of .NET which uses culture-aware comparison by default.

This is obviously a confusing incompatibility between F# and other .NET languages, however it does have some benefits:

- OCAML compat
- String and char comparisons are consistent

  - C# `Comparer<string>.Default.Compare("a", "A") // -1`
  - C# `Comparer<char>.Default.Compare('a', 'A') // 32`
  - F# `compare "a" "A" // 1`
  - F# `compare 'a' 'A' // 32`

**Edit:**

Note that it's misleading (though not incorrect) to state that "F# uses *case-sensitive* string comparison".  F# uses *ordinal* comparison, which is stricter than just case-sensitive.

```
// case-sensitive comparison
StringComparer.InvariantCulture.Compare("[", "A") // -1
StringComparer.InvariantCulture.Compare("[", "a") // -1

// ordinal comparison
// (recall, '[' lands between upper- and lower-case chars in the ASCII table)
compare "[" "A"  // 26
compare "[" "a"  // -6
```

Comment: Thanks @latkin - this is just the kind answer I was looking for - really helpful!

Answer (score 6):

Different libraries make different choices of the default comparison operation on strings. F# is strict defaulting to case sensitivity, while LINQ to Objects is case insensitive.

Both [`List.sortWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370345.aspx) and [`Array.sortWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340274.aspx) allow the comparison to be specified. As does an overload of [`Enumerable.OrderBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549422.aspx).

However the `Seq` module does not appear to have an equivalent (and one isn't being added in 4.6).

For the specific questions:

> Is there an underlying reason for the differences in ordering logic?

Both orderings are valid. In English cases insensitivity seems more natural, because that's what we're used to. But this does not make it more correct.

> What is the recommended way to overcome this "problem" in my situation?

Be explicit about the kind of comparison.

> Is this phenomenon specific to strings, or does it apply to other .NET types too?

`char` will also be affected. And any other type where there is more than one possible ordering (eg. a `People` type: you could order by name or date of birth depending on the specific requirements).

Comment: These are useful comments - thank you.  My understanding (from [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353610.aspx)) was that if a type implements `IComparable` then this is used to do the sorting.  If I explicitly use this interface to implement `IComparer<string>` for the C# version the problem persists.  This suggests that my understanding of how F# does the comparison (even with an `IComparable`) is faulty.  If it would be possible to shed any light on how F# chooses to do the comparison it would be very interesting..

Comment: @Lawrence The docs for `[Seq.sortBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353610.aspx) say it is uses [`Operators.compare`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353429.aspx) but there are no details on that page. Time to read the language spec or the source code ….

Comment: > However the Seq module does not appear to have an equivalent (and one isn't being added in 4.6).<

This is incorrect (or maybe just a typo, or maybe both?).  `Seq.sortWith` has indeed been added in F# 4.0.

Comment: Note that F# uses *ordinal* comparison by default, which is stricter than merely *case-insensitive*.  `char` is compared with ordinal comparison across all the big .NET languages, so unlike `string`, F# users will not be "surprised" at least.

Comment: @latkin I didn't check `Seq` for future versions of F#. WRT ordinal: .NET also supports ordinal case insensitive comparisons, so ordinal is somewhat orthogonal to case sensitivity and rapidly gets into a lot of background detail needed.

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with C# vs F#, or even `IComparable`, but is just due to the different sort implementations in the libraries.

The TL;DR; version is that sorting strings can give different results:

```
"tv" < "TV"  // false
"tv".CompareTo("TV")  // -1 => implies "tv" *is* smaller than "TV"
```

Or even clearer:

```
"a" < "A"  // false
"a".CompareTo("A")  // -1 => implies "a" is smaller than "A"
```

This is because `CompareTo` uses the current culture [(see MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkw3h78a(v=vs.110).aspx).

We can see how this plays out in practice with some different examples.

If we use the standard F# sort we get the uppercase-first result:

```
let strings = [ "UV"; "Uv"; "uV"; "uv"; "Tv"; "TV"; "tv"; "tV" ]

strings |> List.sort 
// ["TV"; "Tv"; "UV"; "Uv"; "tV"; "tv"; "uV"; "uv"]
```

Even if we cast to `IComparable` we get the same result:

```
strings |> Seq.cast<IComparable> |> Seq.sort |> Seq.toList
// ["TV"; "Tv"; "UV"; "Uv"; "tV"; "tv"; "uV"; "uv"]
```

On the other hand if we use Linq from F#, we get the same result as the C# code:

```
open System.Linq
strings.OrderBy(fun s -> s).ToArray()
// [|"tv"; "tV"; "Tv"; "TV"; "uv"; "uV"; "Uv"; "UV"|]
```

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966(v=vs.100).aspx), 
the `OrderBy` method "compares keys by using the default comparer Default."

The F# libraries do not use `Comparer` by default, but we can use `sortWith`:

```
open System.Collections.Generic
let comparer = Comparer<string>.Default
```

Now when we do this sort, we get the same result as the LINQ `OrderBy`:

```
strings |> List.sortWith (fun x y -> comparer.Compare(x,y))
// ["tv"; "tV"; "Tv"; "TV"; "uv"; "uV"; "Uv"; "UV"]
```

Alternatively, we can use the built-in `CompareTo` function, which gives the same result:

```
strings |> List.sortWith (fun x y -> x.CompareTo(y))
// ["tv"; "tV"; "Tv"; "TV"; "uv"; "uV"; "Uv"; "UV"]
```

Moral of the tale: If you care about sorting, always specify the specific comparison to use!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Richard and [his answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30999417/2382536) for pointing me in the direction for getting a little further on in understanding this problem

My problems seem to have been rooted in not fully understanding the consequences of the `comparison` constraint in F#.  Here is the signature of [`Seq.sortBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353610.aspx)

```
Seq.sortBy : ('T -> 'Key) -> seq<'T> -> seq<'T> (requires comparison)
```

My assumption was that if the type `'T` implemented `IComparable` then this would be used in the sorting.  I should have consulted this question first: [F# comparison vs C# IComparable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18091887/f-comparison-vs-c-sharp-icomparable), which contains some useful references, but which require some further careful reading to fully appreciate what is going on.

So, to attempt to answer my own questions:

> Is there an underlying reason for the differences in ordering logic?

Yes. The C# version seems to use the string's implementation of `IComparable`, whereas the F# version does not.

> What is the recommended way to overcome this "problem" in my situation?

Although I cannot comment on whether this is "recommended", the F# function `order` below will use an implementation of `IComparable` if there is one on the relevant type:

```ml
let strings = [| "UV"; "Uv"; "uV"; "uv"; "Tv"; "TV"; "tv"; "tV" |]
let order<'a when 'a : comparison> (sequence: seq<'a>) = 
    sequence 
    |> Seq.toArray
    |> Array.sortWith (fun t1 t2 ->
        match box t1 with
        | :? System.IComparable as c1 -> c1.CompareTo(t2)
        | _ ->
            match box t2 with
            | :? System.IComparable as c2 -> c2.CompareTo(t1)
            | _ -> compare t1 t2)
let orderedValues = strings |> order
```

> Is this phenomenon specific to strings, or does it apply to other .NET types too?

There are clearly some subtleties involved with the relation between the `comparison` constraint and the `IComparable` interface.  To be on the safe side I will follow @Richard's advice and always be explicit about the kind of comparison - probably using the function above to "prioritize" using `IComparable` in the sorting.

Comment: In your code you're sorting twice: first `Seq.sortBy`, then `Array.sortWith`.